# How to open URL in new tab from the Highcharts exporting buttons?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, highcharts

I am adding an extra item to the exporting buttons, via this script:

```
Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
    text: 'Link to more data functions',
    onclick: function () {
        Highcharts.post('http://xxx');
    }
});
```

Now, I'd like to open this link in an extra tab. I looked around, but couldn't find a solution. Tried it like this:

```
Highcharts.post('xxx', {target: "_blank"});
```

but that doesn't work.

I guess there is a solution to this, and probably pretty simple. Can someone please give me a hint? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not `window.open("http://xxx", "_blank");`?

Comment: Ha, haven't thought of that. Great, works fine! Thanks!